# Sending Variable with Post without formular

Tags: php, mysql, json

I execute some PHP code .
After this, I want to send a value over post to another PHP site, which I want use it via `$_POST`. I don't need sessions or cookies or anyway.

```
else if ($tag == 'in_accepted') {
        $coni=mysqli_connect("localhost","LOGIN","PW","movement");
        $tablename = $_POST['tablename'];
        $jsonString = $_POST['json']; 
        $jArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $result2 = mysqli_query($coni, "ALTER TABLE `$tablename` COMMENT = '$comment'");
        $response["comment_succes"] = 1;
        foreach($jArray as $key => $value){
            $ean = $value["ean"];
            //$trimmedean = substr($ean, 0, 3) .".". substr($ean, 3, 4) .".". substr($ean, 7, 4);
            //$result = mysqli_query($coni,"INSERT INTO `$tablename` (unique_id, ean, accepted) VALUES ('$uuid', '$trimmedean', '0')"); // or die(mysql_error());
            $result = mysqli_query($coni, "UPDATE `$tablename` SET accepted='1' where ean='$ean'");
            }
                if ($result > 0) {
                    $response["success"] = 1;
                    !!!!SEND $tablename to URL.php
                    echo json_encode($response);
            }
        else {
                    $response["error"] = 1;
                    echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

Comment: Who upvoted this? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/09/08/http-post-with-php-without-curl/ i foudn that usefull link

Answer (score 0):

1. Use CURL to post the data to the specified url.
2. Make a dynamic form and submit it with the js script/jquery automatically.